# How to reverse Ken Burns effect?

Tags: video, editing

If some videos created by other people have a Ken Burns effect, is it possible for me to remove it and get static full screen view?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect):

> The Ken Burns effect is a type of panning and zooming effect used in film and video production from still imagery.
> The feature enables a widely used technique of embedding still photographs in motion pictures, displayed with slow zooming and panning effects, and fading transitions between frames.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could take screenshots and stitch them together. Any photo editor that has a panorama stitching feature can do this. The question is how sharp are those individual screenshots? It may be necessary to go frame by frame to find the sharpest.